# Transform matrix of 3D positions with corresponding transformation matrix

Tags: transform, eigen

I have a matrix of 3D points (`positions`), in which every column represents a 3D point expressed in a local frame at a specific time instance.

The `transforms` (row)vector contains the transformation matrix of the moving local frame at each time instance, i.e. the ith transformation matrix corresponds with the ith column of `positions`.

I want to calculate the position in the global frame (`transformed`) by applying the transformation matrixes to their corresponding point.

This can be done with a for loop as follows:

```c++
Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Isometry3d, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> transforms;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic> positions, transformed;

for (int i = 0; i < positions.cols(); ++i)
    transformed.col(i) = transforms(i) * positions.col(i);
```

I was wondering if it is possible to perform the same operation avoiding the for loop. I tried the following two approaches, but they are giving me compilation errors:

- Apply the transformation columnwise:

  ```c++
  transformed = transforms.colwise() * positions.colwise ();
  ```

  > error: invalid operands to binary expression (`ColwiseReturnType` (aka  `VectorwiseOp<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 1, 0>, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1>, Vertical>`) and `ColwiseReturnType` (aka `VectorwiseOp<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1, 0, 3, -1>, Vertical>`))
- Apply the transformation using arrays:

  ```c++
  transformed = transforms.array() * positions.array().colwise ();
  ```

  > error: invalid operands to binary expression (`ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 1, 0>, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1> >` and `ColwiseReturnType` (aka `VectorwiseOp<Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, -1, 0, 3, -1> >, Vertical>`))

**Question**: How can I rewrite the for loop to eliminate the (explicit) for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not easy but doable. First you have to tell Eigen that you allow scalar products between an `Isometry3D` and a `Vector3d` and that the result is a `Vector3d`:

```c++
namespace Eigen {
  template<>
  struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Isometry3d,Vector3d,internal::scalar_product_op<Isometry3d,Vector3d> > {
    typedef Vector3d ReturnType;
  };
}
```

Then, you need to interpret your 3xN matrices as a vector of Vector3d using `Map`:

```c++
auto as_vec_of_vec3 = [] (Matrix3Xd& v) { return Matrix<Vector3d,1,Dynamic>::Map(reinterpret_cast<Vector3d*>(v.data()), v.cols()); };
```

Finally, you can use `cwiseProduct` to carry out all products at once:

```c++
as_vec_of_vec3(transformed2) = transforms.cwiseProduct(as_vec_of_vec3(positions));
```

Putting everything together:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

namespace Eigen {
  template<>
  struct ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Isometry3d,Vector3d,internal::scalar_product_op<Isometry3d,Vector3d> > {
    typedef Vector3d ReturnType;
  };
}

int main()
{
  int n = 10;
  Matrix<Isometry3d, 1, Dynamic> transforms(n);
  Matrix<double, 3, Dynamic> positions(3,n), transformed(3,n);

  positions.setRandom();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    transforms(i).matrix().setRandom();

  auto as_vec_of_vec3 = [] (Matrix3Xd& v) { return Matrix<Vector3d,1,Dynamic>::Map(reinterpret_cast<Vector3d*>(v.data()), v.cols()); };

  as_vec_of_vec3(transformed) = transforms.cwiseProduct(as_vec_of_vec3(positions));

  cout << transformed << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but not very general and rather tricky. It wouldn't work if the points are stored as `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3>`, i.e. using a row for each point.

Comment: Is this approach also possible with Eigen 3.2.9 using `internal::scalar_product_traits`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about 3.2.9 but you might try... Regarding the generality of the approach, we could make it easier for the user by 1) using c++11 decltype to avoid the need for `ScalarBinaryOpTraits` and 2) by adding convenient method to see matrices as nested vectors, and the other way round.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I added an answer using `internal::scalar_product_traits`.

Answer (score 1):

*This answers extends ggaels accepted answer to be compatible with versions of Eigen older than 3.3.*

**Pre Eigen 3.3 compatibility**

`ScalarBinaryOpTraits` is introduced in Eigen 3.3 as a replacement for `internal::scalar_product_traits`. Therefore, one should use `internal::scalar_product_traits` before Eigen 3.3:

```
template<> 
struct internal::scalar_product_traits<Isometry3d,Vector3d> {
  enum {Defined = 1};
  typedef Vector3d ReturnType;
};
```